# PHP send MIME emails...doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, email, mime

I just switched from a shared server to a virtual dedicated. The whole site works, but my mail forms have quit sending MIME emails the way they used to.

What used to appear before the server switch:

> hallo fwend

What appears now in the emails (appears as though my client doesn't support MIME):

> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="==DL-
>   bound_b08bcfabdc459ae7e87e493a984115b3"
>
> This is a multipart MIME message from
>   your friends at Example.com. If you
>   are reading this, it seems we have a
>   message to deliver, but your mail
>   client is not set to receive these
>   types of messages. We are sorry for
>   the inconvenience :(
>
> --==DL-bound_b08bcfabdc459ae7e87e493a984115b3
>
> Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=iso-8859-1
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> hallo fwend

Is there some switch in PHP or something that I need turned on to send MIME?

Comment: Are you using a library such as PHPMailer or something to create the multipart MIME mails?

Comment: joel ... no...i custom made my own little class...it seemed to work perfectly before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like the headers are send in the body part of the message.
I had this problem a while back.

Possible causes are:

**1. EOL**
I used "\r\n" as eol for the MIME headers (following the spec)
, but the (shared)server wanted an "\n"

**2. Last header**
Some mail server add some headers of their own. If the last header end with "\n" and the mail  server could also mess thing up.

**3. Empty header**
An empty header which causes a "\n\n" in the $headers will corrupt the headers. The "\n\n" aka "empty line" marks the end of the headers part of a email (or the start of the body)